# How to compose Try with different types arguments?

Tags: scala

If i chain two Try methods with different types in a flatMap, such as:

```scala
def first = Try { "the answer is..." }
def second = Try { 42 }

first flatMap second match {
    case Success(_) => println("Wheeee!!!!")
    case Failure(_) => println("DUH!")
}
```

I'd get a `type mismatch;  found   : scala.util.Try[Int]  required: String => scala.util.Try[?]`

Which clearly i can solve by changing the "second" declaration to:

```
def second(s:String) = Try { 42 }
```

But how could i chain the first and second Try objects without "forcing in" the useless argument?

Answer (score 3):

The error means that the function passed to flatMap is of the wrong type: `type mismatch; found : scala.util.Try[Int] required: String => scala.util.Try[?]`

This can be fixed by supplying a function that takes `x: String` passed on from `first` like so:

```
first flatMap( x => second) match {
  case Success(_) => println("Wheeee!!!!")
  case Failure(_) => println("DUH!")
}                                               //> Wheeee!!!!
```

Comment: The func should be `_ => second` since the point is to ignore the argument.

Comment: FYI, this is pretty much what the `for` comprehension is expanded to by the compiler.

Comment: @DaoWen: Agreed, for essentialy translates to a Map. @som-snytt: Thanks for the `_` wildcard :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `for` comprehension instead:

```
for (f <- first; s <- second) yield s
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is not too obvious to add:

```
if (first.isSuccess && second.isSuccess) "whoopie" else "nope"
```

or

```
implicit def `success is true`[A](t: Try[A]): Boolean = t.isSuccess
println { if (first && second) "whoopie" else "nope" }
```

May all your side effects be local.

Answer (score 1):

You can compose them into tuple and match on both:

```
(first, second) match {
  case (Succcess(_), Success(_)) => ...
  ...
  case (Failure(_), Failure(_)) => ... 
}
```

`flatMap` is an operation with a completely different semantics, if your first `Try` fails, the second won't be computed.